# Sql update in batches

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

What is most effective way to update a table in sql server in order to put a limit of 10k records in one single transaction?

I read about top and `ROWCOUNT` approach by adding it in a while loop. Which is more effective among those?  Or please share if you know alternate effective ways. Thank you.

Comment: what script are you using at the moment?

Comment: DO NOT use ROWCOUNT to control how rows will be updated with an UPDATE statement. It's usage for this has been deprecated and will quit working in the future. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188774.aspx

Comment: Is your intent to update every row 10,000 at a time or just the top 10,000 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one potential approach without using [set rowcount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/ms188774.aspx)

```
-- prepare test data
use tempdb
drop table dbo.t;
create table dbo.t (a int identity, b int)
go
insert into dbo.t ( b)
values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11);
go

-- assume we do 3 records per time, put 10000 here if you wnat 10K records
-- also the update is just to update column [b] to [b] * 2, here is the code

declare @N int = 3; -- do a batch of @N records

declare @i int = 0, @max_loop int;

select @max_loop = count(*)/@N from dbo.t

-- the first batch may include records <= @N-1 and the last batch may include records <= @N
while (@i <= @max_loop)
begin

    ; with c as (
    select rnk=ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a)/@N, a, b from dbo.t
    )
    update c set b = b*2 -- doule b
    where rnk = @i;

    set @i = @i + 1;
end
go
-- check the result
select * from dbo.t
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with the below approach:

```
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE TOP (10000)  XXX
     SET XXX.YYY = <ValueToUpdate>
    FROM XXX   -- Update 10000 nonupdated rows
   WHERE <condition> -- make sure that condition makes sure that it does not become infinite loop
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
      BREAK
   END
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

**EDIT**

Update for all employees of an organization and making sure that it does not become infinte loop. Here, I am updating modifiedDate for an employee record.

```
DECLARE @updatedids table(id int)
WHILE (1=1)
BEGIN
   BEGIN TRANSACTION
  UPDATE TOP(10000)  a    
     SET a.ModifiedDate = GETDATE()
   OUTPUT inserted.BusinessEntityID INTO @updatedids
    FROM HumanResources.Employee  a
LEFT JOIN @updatedids u
    ON a.BusinessEntityID = u.id
    WHERE u.id IS NULL 
  -- Update 10000 nonupdated rows
   IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
   BEGIN
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
      BREAK
   END
   COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

Comment: It will be a dead loop because the same 10000 rows may be updated continuously. (At least in sql server, which I tested)

Comment: I missed WHERE clause. Sorry. I have updated the code. I mainly concentrated on logic.

Comment: For a GENERIC update on a table, there sometimes may not exists a valid condition for you to filter out those already updated. For example, let's say, we have a table with two columns, [emploee_id] and [salary], also let's say, now we want to give a 10% increase to all people, and assuming this table has 1 million rows, now, we want to update this table in 10K/chunk update, how can we come up with a good where clause?

Comment: We should have OUTPUT clause with the UPDATE and store the results in a table variable and make sure that the rows already updated are not updated again.